# Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'SDL2.lib' on microsoft visual studio using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sdl-2

I've been trying to set up a project on Visual Studio, it is working for everyone but me and I cannot understand why. I don't use the project thing on visual studio, I just open the folder with it (and it is working for others so that should not be where the problem is coming from).

Here is my CMake:

```
message(STATUS "Building for windows")

add_compile_definitions(WINDOWSOS)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "SDL2/include")
set(SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS "SDL2_image/include")
if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
message(STATUS "Building for x64")
set(SDL2_LINK_DIRS "SL2/lib/x64")
set(SDL2IMAGE_LINK_DIRS "SDL2_image/lib/x64")
else ()
message(STATUS "Building for x86")
set(SDL2_LINK_DIRS "SDL2/lib/x86")
set(SDL2IMAGE_LINK_DIRS "SDL2_image/lib/x86")
endif ()

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${SDL2_LINK_DIRS}, ${SDL2IMAGE_LINK_DIRS})


message(STATUS ${SDL2_LINK_DIRS})
message(STATUS ${SDL2IMAGE_LINK_DIRS})
add_executable(SDLTest Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SDLTest PUBLIC SDL2 SDL2main SDL2_image)
```

When I right-click on it on the Solution Explorer and click "Configure SDL_Test" everything works, but when I try to "Build everything" in the "Build" menu at the top there is the error mentioned in the title. I was told to add the lib path to my environment variables, which I did:

[image: Path]

And here is what one of the folders looks like:

[image: Folder]

The build is supposed to generate an executable in out/build/x64-Debug/SDL_Test but I do not have one there.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Typo `set(SDL2_LINK_DIRS "SL2/lib/x64")` --> `set(SDL2_LINK_DIRS "SDL2/lib/x64")`

Comment: More typos: the comma in `link_directories(${SDL2_LINK_DIRS}, ${SDL2IMAGE_LINK_DIRS})` should be dropped.